# Is there any way to use simple html instead of jade?

Tags: node.js, pug

I am new to node.js platoform.
By default it uses jade as its template engine.Is there any way to use simple html tags instead of jade?

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js - what are the advantages of using jade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344346/node-js-what-are-the-advantages-of-using-jade)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866289/html-in-express-and-node-js

Comment: i would recommand to stick to jade, it makes writing html a lot faster and the source also looks cleaner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it is possible:

```
var serverHTML = function(res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var body = '<html>' + 
       '<head>' +             
       '<title>Page</title>' +
   '</head>' +
   '<body >' +
   '<center><h1>Hello World</h1></center>' +
   '</body>' +
   '</html>';
    res.end(body + '\n');
}
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    serverHTML(res);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

However, using of template language brings a lot of benefits, like

- putting the templates in different files
- adding content
- using nested templates

If you use pure html you should deal with this by yourself.

There are of course template engines which uses html as base. For example https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/

Answer (score 0):

You ask "Is there any way to use simple html tags instead of jade?"

jade uses simple html tags.  It just doesn't make you repeat them

blah

vs

div
  blah